# Avoiding XSS vulnerabilities in a maven project

Tags: javascript, maven

I develop a frontend. This frontend is a maven project. To avoid the XSS fault, I outsource all javascirpt scripts to other files, and then I call them by doing:

```
<script src = "../ filename.js" type = "text / javascript">
```

in the HTML page. Initially the frontend worked correctly when javascript scripts were mixed with HTML.

My problem is that when I do maven install, all the resources are filtered, but my page is white and the source code actually exists.

How can the content be displayed as if the javascript scripts were not outsourcing?

Comment: it doesn't look like you've finished the question. what goes after 'doing:'?

Comment: This strategy will not help you to avoid XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: Hello,
I develop a frontend. HTML and javascript source code are mixed. The frontentd is currently working well. To avoid XSS vulnerabilities, I have outsourced the javascript scripts into other files. The frontend is a Maven project. When I do Maven install, all the resources are filtered, but the contents of my pages are white and the source code actually exists. To call my external scripts in the HTML page, I did <script src = "../ filename.js" type = "text / javascript">
How do I view the content of my pages?

Comment: I fixed your formatting for you - no need to repeat your question in a comment...

Comment: Please how to avoid xss ?

Comment: Read [Top 10 2017-A3-Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2017-A3-Cross-Site_Scripting_(XSS)), and then investigate the rest of the site.